# Java using Matcher to fail when the immediate sequence is not matchable

Tags: java, regex

Matcher.find finds the next subsequence, starting at a given index, which is compliant with the regex.

How can I make it so that it fails if the next character sequence is not compliant?

Ex:

```
    String input = "123456text123";
    Matcher mat1 = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(input);

    mat1.find();
    System.out.println(mat1.group()); //123456
    mat1.find(mat1.end());
    System.out.println(mat1.group()); //123
```

I want to know if there's a way to make the second find fail, since the next sequence does not match the mat1 pattern.

I want to be able to 'compose' matchers, in such a way that they MUST always be found in sequence.

Is it possible at all?

Comment: You're trying to match 1234foo1234 but not 1234foo123, AND match 4567foo4567 but not 4567foo456?

Comment: @Alex Except that it's impossible to match `\d+` and then succeed in matching it again with no intervening non-matching sequence :)

Comment: @andersoj: His example is not the best. Say the pattern is `a+|b+`. He wants `"aaabb"` to match twice (`"aaa"` then `"bb"`), but "aaaCbb" to match once (`"aaa"`) and then fail (since `"C"` is not matched by the pattern).

Comment: @Amadan If that's all, then his example does not make any sense (either \d+ matches the whole string (success), either it does not (failure)). As for your example, writing [ab]+ will either match the whole string(success), or not (failure). An alternative, would be to look if the current group starts where the previous one ended, meaning that there are nothing that does not match in between

Comment: My example was supposed to be simple to understand. I want to match a given pattern if, and only if, the start of the group is exactly after the last group. As simple as that.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik I cannot understand what he really wants. Really.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet: Rewriting the expression is not the point. His question makes sense if, for example, he's writing a tokenizer, and wants to capture each particular group of characters. In this context, just answering whether the whole string matches or not is not enough. And I agree that aioobe's solution is nice, for what the question asks.

Comment: @Amadan Then simply adding parenthesis around the orignal pattern followed by a '+' will do it too. You first ask the Matcher if it `matches()` and if yes, then you go into the decomposition of the tokens. Or you go with aioobe's solution (I just found out that he wrote what I would have done too).

Comment: Amadan, you got the point. I'm creating a simple parser, and each match should be done in sucession. Sorry if i wasn't clear enough.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet: How do you get `["aaa", "bb"]` from `"aaabb"` by use of `(a+|b+)+`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check that the previous `mat1.end()` equals the next `mat1.start()`.

```
int lastEnd = -1;
while (mat1.find()) {

    // Was there any junk between last two matches?
    if (mat1.start() != lastEnd+1) {
        System.out.println("Fail.");
        break;
    }

    System.out.println(mat1.group());
    lastEnd = mat1.end();

}
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I'm doing, but it's manual and error-prone. If the API could do it for me, it would be way better.

Comment: You can check if str.matches("("+regex+")*") before you start, and then check all together.

Comment: ...or see how far the "("+regex+")*" matches (with a find() / end()) and the restrict attention to the substring.